# Rails in production -- CentOS, Apache, MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm a newly converted LAMP stack developer and wondering how to deploy a rails version of our large scale app.

Our servers currently have:

CentOS
Apache 2.x
MySQL

I've read about products that aid in setting up with this stack (Passenger, etc) but I'm concerned with speed and server load (as our app is already a high trafficked one).

1. **How are people deploying rails applications for production use on a similar setup?**
2. **How could I setup rails to use this existing stack without adding anything else (or only adding production scale components to it)? -- Sort of a LAMR of sorts (Linux Apache MySQL Rails)**

***NOTE: The setup will still serve existing projects that are built with PHP -- so the setup can't really break any existing stack functionality***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger is a good option and is already used by lots of high-traffic sites in production.

Comment: Is it possible to not use Passenger and deploy with just Apache and MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

ad. 1. As you already said, Passenger + REE is popular choice.

ad. 2. You could try to run it with lightweight app server like thin or unicorn. http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/4/17/centos-apache-rails-and-thin

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to not use Passenger and deploy with just Apache and MySQL?

I don't believe you can run rails with only apache and mysql in such a way. Much like the way mod_php takes care of processing the PHP for Apache, a module like passenger (www.modrails.com) takes care of processing the Rails application for you.

You can use the `PassengerEnabled off` ([more info](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerenabled_lt_on_off_gt)) setting in the vhost to disable passenger for the PHP apps. (although your php app will work fine as long as it is not placed in your rails app without this setting.)

About production scale settings. I believe that Twitter used to use apache as a load balancer to a number of mongrel http-servers. ([see this article for some extra information](http://highscalability.com/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster)). As you can see, caching (e.g. memcached) can provide a huge boost to your app if implemented well.